# teb_local_planner development status

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this but I would like to know if the local planner "teb_local_planner" will be further developed?

Most of the commits were in 2016 and minor changes in 2017. The reason I am asking this is that I am using the planner at the moment (works pretty well) and just wanted to know if there will be new features in 2018?

The best person to answers this would be @croessmann (thank you for all your great work) probably.

Thank you guys in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286019/teb_local_planner-development-status/) by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

yeah, there are still some unanswered issues and pull requests for the package.
Unfortunately, I had not much spare-time during the last months to address these issues and to further provide some improvements.
I am going to try to spend some time on improving the planner and check all the pull requests during the next weeks.
I also have some ideas which would require a major update on the code, I will see what I can get in soon.

Cheers,

Christoph

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-03-20**:
Thank you very much for the fast answer, sounds great. I thought you might have finished your research on this topic. The underlying trajectory control in the planner is a model predictive control isn‘t it? Do you have any book recommendations on this topic? I really want to get a deep understanding

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-03-20**:
I have read most  of your conference paper on this topic but it’s a little bit hard for me to understand everything. Maybe you have a good hint for me to get deeper in this topic (my background is computer engineering with two semesters control theory). Thank you very much in advance!